# OpenSea can't read metadata from ERC721 contract

Tags: python, metadata, ipfs, nft, opensea

I'm having trouble getting OpenSea to read metadata from my ERC721 contract. No image, no name, no attributes for NFT as well. I have successfully deployed contract (Goerli Network) via Testnets OpenSea, and uploaded the metadata to IPFS (NFT Storage), made setBaseURI with link to it:

**IPFS and setBaseURI link:** ipfs://bafybeidoxigwtpazvpcuzjko2cceod2zxslsq7zwscqkhq62k2eldkjcpq/

**Smart Contract address:** https://goerli.etherscan.io/token/0x9962a283536dae34b523dbff11bdee389bb7245f

**Pre-reveal image for all NFTs:** ipfs://QmctR6waXc68jq2MExFovvA4U4Z6bbHvz9mZ7ts5dJcMyU/

[Testnets OpenSea link for collection](https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/goerli/0x9962a283536dae34b523dbff11bdee389bb7245f/1)

**TokenID with value 1 return:**

```
string
[ tokenURI(uint256) method Response ]
string :  ipfs://bafybeigs6mexunuhwije6mfmy3jej4ucrpgwfkdh7hzoz7yg3xxg3puatm/1
```

**Generator of metadata map.py**

```
import random
import json
import os

# Load the traits and rarities data
with open("traits.json", "r") as infile:
    traits = json.load(infile)

with open("rarities.json", "r") as infile:
    rarities_data = json.load(infile)

# Create a list of the possible rarities
rarities = [entry["rarity"] for entry in rarities_data["rarities"]]

# Set up the total number of NFTs to generate
total_supply = 10000

# Define the base URI for the metadata
base_uri = "ipfs://QmctR6waXc68jq2MExFovvA4U4Z6bbHvz9mZ7ts5dJcMyU/"

# Create a folder to store the metadata for each NFT
if not os.path.exists("metadata"):
    os.makedirs("metadata")

# Generate the metadata for each NFT
for i in range(1, total_supply+1):
    # Choose a random name from the list of names
    character_index = random.randint(0, len(traits["Name"]) - 1)
    name = traits["Name"][character_index]

    # Choose a random shape and personality for the NFT
    shape = random.choice(traits["Shape"])
    personality = random.choice(traits["Personality"])

    # Get the rarity of the NFT based on the index
    if i-1 < sum(entry["count"] for entry in rarities_data["rarities"]):
        count = 0
        for entry in rarities_data["rarities"]:
            count += entry["count"]
            if i <= count:
                rarity = entry["rarity"]
                break
    else:
        rarity = "Unknown"

    # Create the metadata dictionary for the NFT in OpenSea format
    metadata = {
        "description": f"A {rarity} rarity rainbow creature NFT with a {shape.lower()} body and a {personality.lower()} personality.",
        "image": base_uri,
        "name": f"{name} - {shape} - {personality}",
        "attributes": [
            {"trait_type": "Rarity", "value": rarity},
            {"trait_type": "Shape", "value": shape},
            {"trait_type": "Personality", "value": personality},
        ]
    }

    # Save the metadata to a JSON file
    with open(f"metadata/{i}.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(metadata, outfile, indent=4)

print("Metadata generation complete.")
```

Project was made in Visual Studio Code, metadata was generated by python script.

**Example of 1.json (NFT with ID 1)**

```
{
    "description": "A 1 rarity rainbow creature NFT with a flamboyant body and a calm personality.",
    "image": "ipfs://QmctR6waXc68jq2MExFovvA4U4Z6bbHvz9mZ7ts5dJcMyU/",
    "name": "Pride Lion - Flamboyant - Calm",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "trait_type": "Rarity",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Shape",
            "value": "Flamboyant"
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Personality",
            "value": "Calm"
        }
    ]
}
```

**

I have tried changing the token_uri in the metadata to different formats, but none of them seem to work, looks like i lost something.

I have also tried validating the asset with the following request:

GET /asset/0x9962A283536daE34B523dBff11bdEE389BB7245F/2/validate/

**However, when I try to view the metadata on OpenSea, I get the following "token_uri": null:**

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, GET
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "valid": true,
    "token_uri": null,
    "errors": []
}
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue and how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: And what is the problem with 1.json?

Comment: the problem is, opensea cant read metadata or something like this:



HTTP 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, GET
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "valid": true,
    "token_uri": null,
    "errors": []
}

Comment: Solved. 

What worked for me is removing the file extension from the files so the ipfs url reference didn't have the .json file extension a the end and nor did the tokenURI.

Hope this helps everyone

Comment: You could post this as an actual answer and accept it to make it clear that it solves the problem.